# listing directories as variables and then looping inside each directory in bash

Tags: xml, bash, loops, variables

I have a list of directories

/this/is/my/path/* (dir1, dir2, dir3, etc)

Inside of each of these directories, I have multiple files. The individual names of the files are placed into a .xml document. As of now, I'm calling my script from inside every directory and then manually replacing the directory name in place of **DIRECTORY**, which is located in certain areas within the printed .xml.

Here is the script I use to insert filenames.

```
for i in *.zip ; do
  i="${i%.*}"
  echo "$i";

echo "      <description>
        <name>$i</name>
        <file>this/is/my/path/DIRECTORY/$i.zip</file>
        <partner>/this/is/another/path/DIRECTORY/$i.png</partner>
      </description>">>DIRECTORY-list.xml

done
```

I know I can list the directory names using:

```
dir=/this/is/my/path/*
 for dirs in $dir
 do
   echo `basename $dirs`
```

But obviously that only lists the directories. I need the names of the directories to be placed in variables ($dir1, $dir2, $dir3, etc) and then ran in the 1st script in some kind of loop and then have the end product of the entire loop placed into one giant .xml file.

Things to consider:
-filenames and directory names may or may not have spaces in them.

I hope the question is worded well. Thanks!

Comment: Stick the file loop in the outer loop and prefix `*.zip` with `"$dir"` in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop thru dirs, for each dir, loop thru its files:

```
for dir in /this/is/my/path/*; do
    for i in $dir/*; do
        echo "$i";

        echo "      <description>
    <name>$i</name>
    <file>this/is/my/path/$dir/$i.zip</file>
    <partner>/this/is/another/path/$dir/$i.png</partner>
  </description>" >> $dir-list.xml

    done
done
```

Comment: wow...easy enough. Just to note, I added three new lines above `echo "$i";`. `dir="${dir##*/}"` and `i="${i##*/}"` and `i="${i%.*}"`...just to take out all file paths and extensions without having to use `basename`. Thanks!